# PostgreSQL драйвер для Java

Tags: postgresql, java

В последних релизах PostgreSQL появилась возможность рассылки уведомления об изменениях данных в базе. С точки зрения Java, хотелось бы зарегистрировать свой Listener, для получения таких уведомлений. Ну не дорабатывать же коды драйвера? Может, подскажет кто начинающему))) Кстати, в Qt, может и от недостатка знаний, сформировал сигнал (в кодах драйвера), теперь где нужно программирую слот. Хотя доработку фирменных вещей считаю не очень правильной)))

Answer (score 1):

Штатный JDBC драйвер PostgreSQL поддерживает механизм Listen/Notify. Реализуется посредством интерфейса `Connection`, который в свою очередь реализуется через класс `PGConnection` - надо просто кастировать полученный обычный JDBC коннект на `PGConnection` и вызвать `PGConnection.getNotifications()`. За примером [фтыкать сюда](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/81/listennotify.html)